# jquery file extensions

Tags: jquery

i need one thing to do:

```
<li class="pdf"><a href="#">failanosaukums.pdf</a></li>
<li class="excel"><a href="#">failanosaukums.exel</a></li>
<li class="word"><a href="#">failanosaukums.doc</a></li>
```

If file exstensions are pdf, add li class pdf, and doc, exel, mp3.

I  think something like this

```
var ext = ul li a each split (.) 
$(this).parent().addClass(ext)
```

Comment: Why would you want to achieve this through jQuery? If you have something generating a file list, it seems more sensible to add those classes while generating the rest of the HTML.

Comment: I need this for wordpress attachments plugin. This is one of the easyest ways to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't do this server side when generating the rest of the html, this should work

```
$("ul.files a").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    var ext = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

    $this.parent().addClass(ext);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if what you're wanting is a good idea, but this will do it for you.

```
var files = $("li a");

files.each(function(idx, el) { $(el).parent().addClass($(el).text().split(".").pop()) });
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everybody else that server side is the way to go, but if you must do it client side:

```
$('.downloads li').addClass(function() { 
    return $('a', this).text().split('.').pop();
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/RNvnL/3/

Comment: var files = $(".downloads ul li a");
 files.each(function(idx, el) { $(el).parent().addClass($(el).attr('href').split(".").pop()) });
 $('.downloads ul li').each(function(index) {
    var c_name = $(this).attr('class');
 var txt = $(this).find("a").text();
 $(this).find('a').text(txt+'.'+c_name);
 });